# im trying to put the text at the center in the rect of d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm using d3.js v6 to create a donut graph

I have created the donut and everything the problem is regarding putting the text in rect as mentioned below

Im hoping to achieve the expected result as shown in the image
I've also attached the my current output image below

**Problem**
the only remaining thing that I wanted is the boxes to have the value center aligned

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
        
<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
        
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<style>
.shadow {
        -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
        filter: drop-shadow( 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
      }
</style>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 450,
    height = 450,
    margin = 40;

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${width/2},${height/2})`);

// Create dummy data
var data = {aaa: 9, b: 20, c:30}

// set the color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(d => d[1])
var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data))

// The arc generator
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)

// Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 1)
  .outerRadius(radius * 1)


var div = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0);
// Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
svg
  .selectAll('allSlices')
  .data(data_ready)
  .join('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', d => color(d.data[1]))
  .style("opacity", 0.7)

// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
svg
  .selectAll('allPolylines')
  .data(data_ready)
  .join('polyline')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    
    .attr('points', function(d) {
      var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
      var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
      var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
      var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
      posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
      return [posA, posB, posC]
    })



    
// Add the polylines between chart and labels:


var bars = svg.selectAll("allLabels")
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    
bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class","shadow")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        pos[1]=pos[1]-15;
        if (pos[0]<0){
            pos[0]=pos[0]-30;
        }
        return `translate(${pos})`;
    })
    .attr("width",  function(d) {
        return "30"
    })
    .attr("height", "30")
    .attr('rx', 5)
    
    .attr("fill","white")

    
    //.attr("r", "10")
    

bars.selectAll("rect")
    .append('text')
    .text(d => d.data[0])
    .style('text-anchor','middle')
</script>
```

**current output**
[image]

**Expected Result**
[image]

Any help or guidance will be a great  help

Comment: use `text-anchor: middle` and `alignment-baseline: middle`

Comment: bars.selectAll("rect")
 .append('text')
    .text(d => d.data[0])
    .style('text-anchor','middle')
    .style('alignment-baseline','middle')   i did that but it didnt worked out

Comment: i believe im making a mistake at very basic level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a few problems in your code:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 450,
    height = 450,
    margin = 40;

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${width/2},${height/2})`);

// Create dummy data
var data = {aaa: 9, b: 20, c:30}

// set the color scale
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
  .range(d3.schemeDark2);

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3.pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(d => d[1])
var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data))

// The arc generator
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.5)         // This is the size of the donut hole
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)

// Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
var outerArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 1)
  .outerRadius(radius * 1)


var div = d3.select("#my_dataviz").append("div")
    .style("opacity", 0);
// Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
svg
  .selectAll('allSlices')
  .data(data_ready)
  .join('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', d => color(d.data[1]))
  .style("opacity", 0.7)

// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
svg
  .selectAll('allPolylines')
  .data(data_ready)
  .join('polyline')
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    
    .attr('points', function(d) {
      var posA = arc.centroid(d) // line insertion in the slice
      var posB = outerArc.centroid(d) // line break: we use the other arc generator that has been built only for that
      var posC = outerArc.centroid(d); // Label position = almost the same as posB
      var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2 // we need the angle to see if the X position will be at the extreme right or extreme left
      posC[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1); // multiply by 1 or -1 to put it on the right or on the left
      return [posA, posB, posC]
    })



    
// Add the polylines between chart and labels:


var bars = svg.selectAll("allLabels")
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2
        pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        pos[1]=pos[1]-15;
        if (pos[0]<0){
            pos[0]=pos[0]-30;
        }
        return `translate(${pos})`;
    })
    
bars.append("rect")
    .attr("class","shadow")
    .attr("width",  function(d) {
        return "30"
    })
    .attr("height", "30")
    .attr('rx', 5)
    .attr("fill","white")

    
bars.append('text')
    .text(d => d.data[0])
    .attr('dx', 15)
    .attr('dy', 15)
    .style('text-anchor','middle')
    .style('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
```

```css
.shadow {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow( 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
  filter: drop-shadow( 4px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks michael it had worked ..but the thing is if I try to increase the width of the box , the text is no longer certer aligned

Comment: can you tell me what im missing now I I tried increasing the width to 50 px just for your information @Michael Rovinsky

Comment: @SachinRajput set `bars.append('text')....attr('dx', 25)`